# Efficient way to compute SparseMatrix 1-norm, Inf-norm in Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

In Eigen library, I know that there are *visitors* and *reductions* for dense `Eigen::Matrix` class which I can use efficiently to compute their *1-norm*, *inf-norm*, *etc.* someway like this:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A;
...
A.colwise().lpNorm<1>().maxCoeff();
A.rowwise().lpNorm<1>().maxCoeff();
// etc.
```

Now I have sparse `Eigen::SparseMatrix` class. How can I efficiently compute these norms in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the colwise/rowwise 1-norm using a product with a vector of ones:

```
(Eigen::RowVectorXd::Ones(A.rows()) * A.cwiseAbs()).maxCoeff();
(A.cwiseAbs() * Eigen::VectorXd::Ones(A.cols()).maxCoeff();
```

Check the generated assembly to see if this gets sufficiently optimized for your purpose. If not, or if you need other `lpNorm`s, you may need to write two nested loops with sparse iterators.